# Python: Find identical items in multiple lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list of an arbitrary number of lists, for instance:

```
[[1,2,3], [3,4,5], [5,6,7], [7,8,9]]
```

Now I would like a list containing all elements that are present in more than one list:

```
[3,5,7]
```

How would I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The same way as you'd do it by hand:

```
seen = set()
repeated = set()
for l in list_of_lists:
  for i in set(l):
    if i in seen:
      repeated.add(i)
    else:
      seen.add(i)
```

By the way, here's the one liner (without counting the import) that some people were seeking (should be less efficient than the other approach)

```
from itertools import *
reduce(set.union, (starmap(set.intersection, combinations(map(set, ll), 2))))
```

Comment: Just be careful, as `l` needs also to be 'setted', or you'll get false positives in [[1,1],[2,2]]

Comment: as @Khelben says you should change `for i in l:` in `for i in set(l):`

Comment: With @Khelben's correction applied that solution worked well. Thanks!

Comment: @Khelben thanks for pointing out, I was already thinking in "set mode" instead of lists ^_^

Comment: I like the approach. One might want to wrap it into a function for easier use.

Answer (score 7):

Cleanest way would probably be to use reduce:

```
def findCommon(L):
    def R(a, b, seen=set()):
        a.update(b & seen)
        seen.update(b)
        return a
    return reduce(R, map(set, L), set())

result = findCommon([[1,2,3], [3,4,5], [5,6,7], [7,8,9]])
```

Result is a set, but just do `list(result)` if you really need a list.

Comment: @Dyno the `seen` variable contains a "hidden" mutable state between calls... functional programming shouldn't rely on side effects (and it's a peril if they are not explicit, I bet that most of people wouldn't notice that seen is playing the role of a "static" variable instead of a regular argument)

Comment: @fortran: The typical usage of functions such as R is one-time, since they are placed inside another function and not at module level.  I'll update the answer to make that clearer.

Comment: I know that, but even with that premises an incautious reader could be fooled... I think it would be cleaner to move `seen` outside the parameter list of `R` and make it a local variable of `findCommon`.

Answer (score 6):

This only finds elements common to **all** lists (i.e, the intersection):

```
 set.intersection(*[set(list) for list in list_of_lists])
```

Comment: this returns empty set when i plug in the original list `[[1,2,3], [3,4,5], [5,6,7], [7,8,9]]` i think its meant as a intersection of all lists ?

Comment: I haven't invested much time in it, but it is not the solution to the OPs question.

Comment: I've updated the answer to clarify that it only finds the intersection.

Answer (score 3):

reference: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set

```
#!/usr/bin/python

ll = [[1,2,3], [3,4,5], [5,6,7], [7,8,9]]
ls = [set(l) for l in ll]

su = ls[0]  #union
ssd = ls[0] #symmetric_difference
for s in ls[1:]:
  su = su.union(s)
  ssd = ssd.symmetric_difference(s)

result = su.difference(ssd)
print list(result)
```

=>

```
[3, 5, 7]
```

revise and adopt FP,

```
ll = [[1,2,3], [3,4,5], [5,6,7], [7,8,9]]

u = reduce(set.union, map(set, ll))
sd = reduce(set.symmetric_difference, map(set, ll))
print u - sd
```

=>

```
[3, 5, 7]
```

Comment: Actually your solution is not correct with my test case like `lst_of_lst=[[65L, 66L, 81L, 95L, 96L, 128L, 171L, 193L, 218L, 304L, 305L, 338L, 353L, 355L, 357L, 412L],
            [86L, 98L, 154L, 356L],
            [75L, 154L],
            [38L, 57L, 65L, 145L, 175L, 264L, 325L, 420L, 429L, 439L],
            [75L, 161L],
            [66L, 109L, 128L, 137L, 142L, 154L, 183L, 184L, 187L, 203L, 233L, 285L, 289L, 343L]]`  the result should be `[128L, 65L, 66L, 154L, 75L]`,but your solution miss `154L`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
data = [[1,2,3], [3,4,5], [5,6,7], [7,8,9], [1,2,3]]

res = set()

for i in data:
    for j in data:
        if i is not j:
            res |= set(i) & set(j)

print res
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary to get the count of each

```
from collections import defaultdict

init_list = [[1,2,3], [3,4,5], [5,6,7], [7,8,9]]
#defaultdict, every new key will have a int(0) as default value
d = defaultdict(int)
for values in init_list:
  #Transform each list in a set to avoid false positives like [[1,1],[2,2]]
  for v in set(values):
    d[v] += 1

#Get only the ones that are more than once
final_list = [ value for value,number in d.items() if number > 1 ]
```

Comment: @muhuk. Yes! you're absolutely right! I've changed the code. The standard library of Python is really big and full of useful things...

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> sets = [[1,2,3], [3,4,5], [5,6,7], [7,8,9]]
>>> seen = set()
>>> duplicates = set()
>>> 
>>> for subset in map(set, sets) :
...     duplicates |= (subset & seen)
...     seen |= subset
... 
>>> print(duplicates)
set([3, 5, 7])
>>>
```

I tried for a one-line answer with map/reduce, but can't quite get it yet.

Answer (score 1):

I am still learning but would like to share my answer.

```
num_list1 = ['3', '6', '5', '8', '33', '12', '7', '4', '72', '2', '42', '13']
num_list2 = ['3', '6', '13', '5', '7', '89', '12', '3', '33', '34', '1', '344', '42']

result = [int(num) for num in num_list1 if num in num_list2)
print(result)
```

This prints:

```
[3, 6, 5, 33, 12, 7, 42, 13]
```

Comparing all elements in both lists and creating a new list with similar elements. And turning them into integers.

Answer (score 0):

```
l=[[1,2,3], [3,4,5], [5,6,7], [7,8,9]]
d={}
for x in l:
    for y in x:
        if not d.has_key(y):
            d[y]=0
        d[y]+=1
[x for x,y in d.iteritems() if y>1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my go:

```
seen = set()
result = set()
for s in map(set, [[1,2,3], [3,4,5], [5,6,7], [7,8,9]]):
    result.update(s & seen)
    seen.update(s)
print result
```

This prints:

```
set([3, 5, 7])
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use a set see http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set

Answer (score -3):

flatten, sort, 1 for loop comparing numbers before and after

Comment: This would fail if a number occurs twice in the same list.

Comment: If you flatten first, you would get a "false positive" on input such as: [[1, 1], [2, 2]]