# How to compare list of lists (with N items) for items that are repeated, but only in different lists

Tags: python

I'm coming back to programming after years off and am having trouble wrapping my head around this problem. The user is defining the Classification set amount but the RasterValue is list is of length N

Example:
    ClassificationSet = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) #defined by user 
    RasterVal = () #length = N

I store items into RasterVal using ClassificationSet as an index:
    RasterVal(ClassificationSet).add(Imported Value)

```
RasterVal(1) = 22,23,24,25,23,23,22
RasterVal(2) = 22,30,31,32,30,30
RasterVal(3) = 31
```

which is: RasterVal([],[22,23,24,25,23,23,22], [22,30,31,32,30,30], [31])

I want to list values that are repeated but only if they are repeated in different sets, not the same one.

Output should be:
    RepeatSet = 22, 31

Thank you very much for any help. I've been able to compare the sets but it lists repeated values even if they appear in the same set list.

Comment: You could try using a `set` and a `Counter` together to get it done.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116286/python-find-identical-items-in-multiple-lists

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@lukecampbell is right:

```
>>> lsts = [[22,23,24,25,23,23,22],[22,30,31,32,30,30],[31]]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter(x for lst in lsts for x in set(lst))
>>> [x for x,y in c.items() if y > 1]
[22, 31]
```

The runtime of this algorithm is linear, rather than quadratic in the number of sets.

Answer (score 2):

```
RasterVal = [[22,23,24,25,23,23,22],[22,30,31,32,30,30],[31]]

from itertools import combinations
out = set()
for a,b in combinations(RasterVal,2):
    out = out|(set(a)&set(b))

print out
#output:
set([22, 31])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#-- Your initial data...
rasterVals = [
    (22,23,24,25,23,23,22),
    (22,30,31,32,30,30),
    (31,)
]

#-- This will be a set, which holds only distinct values.
repeated = set( )

#-- We set up a classic inner-outer loop to iterate over all 
#-- pairs of lists in your given data.  (Note, there are better ways
#-- of doing this in Python, but this is the easiest to read and understand)
for a in rasterVals:
    #-- First, we'll make a set from the first element.
    #-- Since sets only hold distinct values, any repeated numbers
    #-- in the sequence will be ignored.
    s = set(a)

    for b in rasterVals:
        #-- Test that we are not comparing a sequence to itself.
        if (a is not b):
            #-- Make a set for the inner loop. (again, only distinct numbers...)
            t = set(b)

            #-- Get the intersection of s and t, answering with only those elements
            #-- that are in both s and t.
            intersecting = (s & t)

            #-- We update our set of (inter-sequence) repeated elements.
            repeated.update(intersecting)

#-- Show the results.
print repeated
```